# Power-shell Script to check if a local admin account exists on remote windows Machine

Tags: powershell

Need inputs to create a power shell script to run on remote machine to check whether local admin account exist on that machine
If yes report it to manage engine desktop central or send an email

Any ideas would be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Not sure what "manageengine desktop central" is but you can use `Invoke-command` to run a command on a remote computer. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXX -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators"}`. This will get you a list of local admin users on that remote computer.